# do post processing after make install in cmake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to make a copy of my executable at the end of my"make install"

I need to do something like:

```
cp bin/prog bin/prog1
```

I have added the following as the last line in my CMakelists.txt

```
install (CODE  "execute_process(COMMAND /src/copyExe.sh ${BIN_DIR})")
```

copyExe.sh is a bash script that does the copying.  In order to have the desired affect, I need to run "make install" twice.  The first time it complains that prog doesn't exist, and then copies the file to bin.  The second time it finds prog and is able to make the copy.

Is there a way to ensure that my copyExe script runs AFTER the files get copied to bin?

Directory structure

```
site
    bin
    src
        CMakeLists.txt ( contains add_dir(foo) and install(CODE....))
    foo
        CMakeLists.txt ( contains install( TARGET..... ))
```

Comment: `copies the file to bin` - this is done by `install(TARGETS <exe-target> ...)` command, right? Where is this command placed (relatively to `install(CODE)` one)?

Comment: I edited the original post to include the directory structure.  The source code is in foo

Answer (score 2):

While CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/install.html) for `install` command says (about installation logic):

> The order across directories is not defined.

it looks like it tends to process installation logic in different **subdirectories in the same order** as `add_subdirectory()` calls.

However, it processes installation logic of `install()` call in the *current directory* **before ones in subdirectories**.

You may move `install(CODE)` into some subdirectory (say, `fix_binaries`), and add this subdirectory at the end of `CMakeLists.txt` in `src`:

**src/fix_binaries/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
install(CODE ...)
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
add_subdirectory(foo)
...
# After all add_subdirectory() calls
add_subdirectory(fix_binaries)
```

Such approach works for one of the project I have involved ([related code](https://github.com/euspectre/kedr/blob/master/sources/cmake/modules/update_modules.cmake)).