# CPack and INSTALL(SCRIPT...)

Tags: cmake, cpack

I would like to use `INSTALL(SCRIPT custom-script.cmake)` during the package generation with `CPack` to apply some transformations on the files previously installed with `INSTALL(FILE...)`.

The problem is that the script should somehow know the "buildroot" of the package (that is, for example, `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_CPack_Packages/<Platform>/<CPack_Generator>/<package_name>_<version>_<arch>/`).

It seems the script doesn't receive neither `${DESTDIR}`, nor appropriately modified `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` nor CPack-specific variables like `CPACK_TEMPORARY_INSTALL_DIRECTORY` or `CPACK_TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY` which are mentioned when one launches `cpack` with `--debug` switch.

Additionally, it seems that `INSTALL(SCRIPT...)` is executed *before* other `INSTALL()s` even if it's placed at the end of `CMakeLists.txt`.

Is it possible to arrange cmake `install`s or other machinery to achieve the goal — to run a custom script on `install`ed files and directories?

Comment: About `install(SCRIPT)` ordering see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875499/do-post-processing-after-make-install-in-cmake.

Comment: Likely the whole approach is incorrect so I would like to accept your answer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @user3159253 Did you ever find out how to get the value of "buildroot" in the script?

Comment: @magjac no, we had to switch back to modification of the files to install on earlier stages of the build process :/. Yeah, the  approach is far from perfect, but at least it works for simple needs.

Comment: I feel like the title of this post can be improved, but don't feel well positioned to do it myself. Could you try to make it more representative of the question here? Maybe useful: [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587) Note: yes, I recognize that this is quite an old post, but it's precisely because it has value (upvotes) that I think this would be a valuable thing to do.