# CMake - how to call installation commands from the top level AFTER these commands from subdirectories?

Tags: cmake

My project contains a top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, which has this structure:

```
add_subdirectory(piece1)
add_subdirectory(piece2)
# --- etc.

install(CODE "execute_process(...)")
```

When I do `make install` all the installation commands from this file are called *first* - and it's not good for me, cause I need to setup symlinks and to do other steps, which require presence of files in destination directories.

So, I want to tell CMake to call `install` commands from this file *after* all the `install` commands from all my subdirectories.

How to do that?

Comment: Move `install(CODE)` into a subdirectory, like described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875499/do-post-processing-after-make-install-in-cmake/43899715#43899715).

Comment: @Tsyvarev - thanks, it worked... You could translate this into an answer

Comment: Actually, I find your question to be a *duplicate* of the referenced one. It is true that you have quite a different wording and have already found how CMake orders installations. But the ultimate problem is the same. Stack Overflow prevents marking as a duplicate until upvoted/accepted answer. But I don't find a copy-pasting of my answer here to be a right way. Could you upvote my referenced answer (as it works for you), so it will be possible to mark it as a duplicate? Note, that you wont get your question closed, your question will remain searchable and will be able to get upvotes.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - I've upvoted the answer you've suggested. As for my question - I think it happened to be formulated more clearly than the question you've answered earlier, so it would make sense to give it a short answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `install(CODE)` into subdirectory (but add this subdirectory at the end ot the script, after others `add_subdirectory` calls).

I know no other ways to force CMake to execute your installation code after all others.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875499/do-post-processing-after-make-install-in-cmake/43899715#43899715) to the related question.